# MAAS: Works with the GUI but the CLI says "409 CONFLICT"

Tags: server, juju, maas

Maas works via the web interface without problem. But when I try with the command line it gives me the "typical" 409 CONFLICT error.

I am using ubuntu server 14.04 LTS with MaaS (1.7.6) installed from the ISO.
The web interface shows 6 nodes with status "Deployed", and they do actually work fine.

Now, from the CLI:

```
maas my-maas nodes acquire --debug
409 CONFLICT

     Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
             Date: Thu, 12 Nov 2015 13:37:02 GMT
           Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
           Status: 409
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
             Vary: Cookie
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

No node available.
```

The "default" zone on the GUI says 6 nodes, and on the UI:

```
maas my-maas zone read default
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
{
    "resource_uri": "/MAAS/api/1.0/zones/default/", 
    "name": "default", 
    "description": ""
}
```

If I try with juju, it won't kickstart, and it complains about not having available nodes on the "default" zone.

```
juju quickstart
juju quickstart v1.3.1
bootstrapping the maas environment (type: maas)
juju-quickstart: error: Bootstrapping environment "maas"
Starting new instance for initial state server
Launching instance
WARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: cannot start bootstrap 
instance: cannot run instances: cannot run instances: gomaasapi: 
got error     back from server: 409 CONFLICT (No available node 
matches constraints: zone=default)

ERROR subprocess encountered error code 1
```

Maybe something is overwriting the "default" string in somewhere, but I don't know yet how to solve it. Is somebody familiar with this issue?

I just made a fresh install and followed the instructions step by step. So I shouldn't be the only one with this problem...

Update:

OK, so thanks to the comment of Andreas I assume that I can't run "juju quickstart" on "Ready" state. So, do I need to de-allocate a node and run the command again before commisioning the node?

Answer (score 2):

If you have only 6 nodes and they are in the deployed state, then there are no more nodes to acquire, that's why you get the 409 error. You can only acquire ("allocate") nodes that are in the READY state.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! But, how can I then run the "juju quickstart" command successfully? Isn't it supposed to start one of the "ready" nodes and install the juju web interface on it?

Comment: It is supposed to start one of the "ready" nodes, yes. Note that "ready" != "allocated" or "deployed", and only "ready" nodes can be taken by juju. If you have "ready" nodes and juju still won't grab them, then maybe you are specifying constraints that exclude those "ready" nodes.